Spring Boot update of authenticated user data
When I update the user who is logged in, it does not refresh the data on the fly, when I call it from User userDetails = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
`@GetMapping("/gestion-usuarios/editar-usuario/{id}")
    public String getEditUserForm(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        User userDetails = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        user.setConfirmPassword(user.getPassword());
        user.setConfirmEmail(user.getEmail());
        model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.getAllRolesByEnabled());
        model.addAttribute("teams", teamService.getAllTeamsByEnabled());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("navConfig", "active");
        model.addAttribute("navUsers", "active");
        model.addAttribute("editMode", true);
        model.addAttribute("authUser", userDetails);
        return "/security-management/users/user-form";
    }

`

I take the id of the logged in user and get it back from the database, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

Where do you load the updated user? in another request or in another method call? Show your code, which is accessing the user.
